# Appending a list with an array during a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop

I'm very new to python and I've become a bit unstuck.

I'm trying to run a for loop which adds 1 to every element of a 2x2 array. However, I want to store each matrix after each loop. I am using .append() to do this but it seems to only store the final result multiple times.

```
result = []

def f():  
  x= np.matrix([[1, 2],[3, 4]])
  for i in range(5):
     result.append(x)
     x += 1
  return result

function = f()

print function
```

But the output is:

```
[matrix([[6, 7],
    [8, 9]]), matrix([[6, 7],
    [8, 9]]), matrix([[6, 7],
    [8, 9]]), matrix([[6, 7],
    [8, 9]]), matrix([[6, 7],
    [8, 9]])]'
```

Which is just a repeat of the last iteration instead of logging all the results.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check my answer below? is that what you want exactly?

Comment: I have explained why what happens in your question happens, along with a solution in my answer below. Let me know if you still have any doubts :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import numpy as np

result = []

def f():
  x = np.matrix([[1, 2],[3, 4]])
  for i in range(5):
     result.append(x + i)
  return result

res = f()
```

**Result:**

```
>>> res
[matrix([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]]), matrix([[2, 3],
        [4, 5]]), matrix([[3, 4],
        [5, 6]]), matrix([[4, 5],
        [6, 7]]), matrix([[5, 6],
        [7, 8]])]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that is happening is that in the backend, Python handles everything through pointers. Hence, whenever you are appending `x`, you are just appending a pointer to `x`. But, then, at each stage, you are just appending a pointer which points to the same location. Hence, they all point to a matrix which stores the final value of the matrix `x`. Instead, you should create a copy of the matrix by appending x.copy()`. The modified code would be :

```
result = []

def f():  
  x= np.matrix([[1, 2],[3, 4]])
  for i in range(5):
     result.append(x.copy())
     x += 1
  return result

function = f()

print(function)
```

When I try it on my Python 3, I get the output

```
[matrix([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]]), matrix([[2, 3],
        [4, 5]]), matrix([[3, 4],
        [5, 6]]), matrix([[4, 5],
        [6, 7]]), matrix([[5, 6],
        [7, 8]])]
```

Comment: @seewaq if my answer helped you, kindly accept it as the answer and upvote it :-) See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for more details